# how to return html code and php value in one ajax call

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, return-value

i have a simple ajax call which returns html codes,

```
//=======-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-==-=-=-=-=
//SEARCH Submit ===============================================================================
$('.clicked_search').live("click",function() {
var from = $('#from').val();
var to = $('#to').val();
var sel = $('#sel').val();

var BegDT = new Date(from);
var EndDT = new Date(to);
var sum = BegDT - EndDT;
alert (BegDT +" b"+ EndDT +" e"+ sum);
if(sum > 0 | from == "" & to != "" | from != "" & to == ""){
$('.inv_date').show();
}
else{
    $("#app_panel").html('<div id="flash" align="left"  ><img src="img/clientimg/ajax.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Request...</span></div>');
    $("#clock").html('<div id="flash2" align="left"  ><img src="img/clientimg/ajax.gif" height="15px" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading"><font size="1">Loading Request...</font></span></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "database/clientpanel/logs/search_call_log.php",
        data: {
            from: from,
            to: to,
            sel: sel
            },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#flash").hide();
            $('.inv_date').hide();
            $("#app_panel").append(html);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "database/clientpanel/logs/search_clock_log.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#flash2").hide();
            $('.inv_date').hide();
            $("#clock").append(html);
        }
    });
}   
return false;
});
```

but i also want it to return values that was produced from the php which the ajax called,

```
session_start();
include("../../dbinfo.inc.php");

// connect to the database
  $client_id = $_SESSION['clientid'];
//===========THIS PHP VALUES RIGHT HERE===================================
      $out = 0;  
      $in = 0;
      $ext =0;
      $min = 0;
      $sec = 0;
//====================================================================
  $query=" select * from call where client='$client_id' ORDER BY date_time DESC";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

how can i return the "html code" together with the "php values" using one ajax call?

Comment: still working on it, sorry for the mess XD

Comment: The line `$query = "select * from call where client='$client_id' ORDER BY date_time DESC";` is potentially vulnerable. Although client_id might be not be directly defined by the user and not as vulnerable as it could be, such ways are best avoided. Consider using [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could transfer your data in a JSON format.

Within your PHP, you'll build an array with all the data you want to pass back for the AJAX call.

```
$results = array(
  'html' => $html,
  'variable1'=>'value1',
  'variable2'=>'value2',
  ...
);
```

Now you encode this array into a JSON format using [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) -

```
$jsonString = json_encode($results);
echo $jsonString;
```

This is the value that you echo out of your PHP.

Now in your jQuery `$.ajax` request, you'll need to specify the `dataType:json`, and you'll be able to access all the parameters in your success callback -

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  ...
  success: function(data){
    ...
    $("#app_panel").append(data.html);
    // also available :
    // data.variable1 and data.variable2
  }
});
```

Comment: how can i do this part 'html' => $html, should i put all of the html code on a php value?

Comment: You should use `.html(data.html)` instead.

Comment: @tel - yes. Just place all of the html code within a php variable and place that variable in the array...

Comment: should i do it like this? " $html = $html + $html; " because my html code is on a while loop and the code repeats untill the whole table is finish?

Comment: @tel - indeed! You have the logic correct, but in PHP, you can use the `.` character (period) to concatenate strings. `"Hello" . "world";`.  [See the PHP documentation for details](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: i have a problem the string value isn't being pass to my ajax but there is no error on my php script